# TCP connection error when outgoing post

Tags: ruby

I try to apply an sms api to my code to my system and stuck at posting data. I  followed the sample code found online to post the data, but getting the error at below. I'm sure the host is valid and my internet connection is fine.

> `rescue in block in connect': Failed to open TCP connection to
>   https://rest-api.moceansms.com:443 (getaddrinfo: No such host is
>   known. ) (SocketError)

Below is my code

```
require "net/http"
url = 'https://rest-api.moceansms.com'
uri = '/rest/1/sms'
params = {'mocean-api-key'=>'mykey','mocean-api-secret'=>'secret','mocean-to'=>'60162211800','mocean-from'=>'63001','mocean-text'=>'Hello world!!!'}

begin
    http = Net::HTTP.new(url,443)  
    http.use_ssl = true
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
    if params.size > 0
        request.form_data = params
    end
    puts http.request(request)
rescue Exception
    raise Exception.new('Unable connect to host')
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error because of url including "https://" , work after remove "https://" from url

Comment: Can you specify what have you removed to make it work.